# squid авторизация

Tags: squid

squid-3.5
Настроена авторизация в active directory.
При логине пользователя на компьютер(Windows), прокси авторизует всё ПО и браузер автоматически в текущем сеансе.
Подскажите, нужно сделать, чтобы при каждом обращении к прокси, появлялся запрос на авторизацию на прокси, т.е. например при кадом открытии браузера.
Через GPO не катит в моём случае.

Comment: У вас скорее всего сейчас настроена Kerberos/NTLM аутентификация. Прикрутите Basic аутентификацию и всё должно получиться по плану.

Comment: de_frag, а т.е. следом за Kerberos/NTLM в конфиге ещё basic описать? Спасибо.

Comment: Ну тут скорее смысл в том, что по итогу надо. если речь идет о том, чтобы спрашивало пароль всех без разбора, тогда аутентификацию надо заменить. А если только для избранных, то тут надо подумать. У вас какая задача?

Comment: Чтобы в текущем сеансе спрашивал пароль у всех доменных пользователей.

Comment: Тогда «прозрачную» аутентификацию в сквиде надо совсем убрать и оставить только Basic. Будет спрашивать пароль, но и будет его кэшировать на определенное время. Время кэширования, если не ошибаюсь, можно регулировать.

Comment: de_frag, да работает через basic.